# XSLT version - Oracle Service Bus

Tags: xslt, oracle11g, osb

Which version of XSLT does Oracle Service Bus 11.1.1.6 provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as its part of the SOA Suite, see this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_xslt_mpr.htm#SOASE188

> Version 1.0 of XSLT is supported.

Comment: It contained a link to the standards to XSLT, that link I mean. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Service Bus 11.1.1.6 supports XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It support XSLT 1.0 but it is better to use XQuery in Oracle Service Bus.